# C: Adjacency lists from graph - segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

NOTE: I can't use '.' and '->' operators on a graph. That's why I use these macros.

For the following declaration of graph (that I cannot change - assignment, so please don't ask me anything about it),

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAG(vp)   ((vp)->tag)
#define LABEL(vp) ((vp)->label)  
#define EDGE(vp)  ((vp)->edge)

typedef struct vertex 
{
    char tag; /* can be used for any puproses; haven't used though */
    char *label;
    struct vertex *edge[1];
}
vertex, *vp;
```

I wrote the following structure and function that creates adjacency lists for graph.

```
typedef struct adjList
{
    vp node;
    struct adjList *next;
}
adjList;


void createList (adjList *list, vp graph, int *place) /* place stores an index in an array of adjacency lists */
{
    int i, temp = *place;
    adjList *ptr;
    if (graph)
    {
        list[temp].node = graph;
        list[temp].next = NULL;
        if (EDGE (graph))
        {
            ptr = list[temp].next;
            for (i = 0; EDGE (graph)[i]; ++i)
            {
                ptr = malloc (sizeof (adjList));
                ptr->node = EDGE (graph)[i];
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
        ++(*place);
        list = realloc (list, sizeof (adjList) * (*place + 1));
        for (i = 0; EDGE (graph)[i]; ++i)
        {
            createList (list, EDGE (graph)[i], place);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this main, I get a segmentation fault.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int *temp = malloc (sizeof (int));
    adjList *list, *ptr;
    vp test;
    *temp = 0; /* temp is an index starting from 0 */
    test = malloc (sizeof (*test) + 4 * sizeof (vp));
    list = malloc (sizeof (adjList));
    LABEL (test) = malloc (sizeof (char));
    LABEL (test)[0] = 'a';
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        EDGE (test)[i] = malloc (sizeof (vertex));
    }
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[0]) = malloc (sizeof (char));
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[0])[0] = 'b';
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[1]) = malloc (sizeof (char));
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[1])[0] = 'c';
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[2]) = malloc (sizeof (char));
    LABEL (EDGE (test)[2])[0] = 'd';
    EDGE (EDGE (test)[0])[0] = NULL;
    EDGE (EDGE (test)[1])[0] = NULL;
    EDGE (EDGE (test)[2])[0] = NULL;
    EDGE (test)[3] = NULL;
    printf ("%d\n", sizeof (EDGE (test)) / sizeof (vp));
    createList (list, test, temp);
    list = realloc (list, sizeof (adjList) * (*temp));
    printf ("%c\n", LABEL (test)[0]);
    printf ("%d\n", (test == list[0].node));
    for (ptr = list; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
        printf ("%c ", LABEL (ptr->node)[0]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

While debugging it, I found that my function that creates adjacency lists does not even store pointers in "adjList" structures. Maybe I'm not allocating memory properly. Any bit of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `EDGE(EDGE(test)) = NULL;` - what if one day somebody turns `EDGE` into a function? Learn some style, really...

Comment: in this assignment i can't use '.' and '->' operators on a graph, so sorry

Comment: as well as i can't change declarations and macros

Comment: @Kudayer what a silly assignment... but you're still using those operators!

Comment: on a graph, not on an adjacency lists (but you are right - silly assignment)

Comment: ;) at least they didn't say anything about lists

Comment: Just as in the previous (now deleted) version of this question ([SO 16883258](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16883258) for 10k users), you are missing the NOFELEMS macro which has a decent chance of being a source of crashes since it is still not clear how you know how long the list of edges is.  You also still have member `tag` and macro `TAG` that are unused in the funcion.  Please pay attention to what an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) is.  You are close; you are not there yet.

Comment: i guess, now it should work

Comment: OK - NOFELEMS is now gone from the code; thanks.  We may be able to compile what you've got.  The macros are still objectionable, but seem to be a property of the exercise rather than personal choice.  It still seems funny to use an 8-byte pointer and an allocation of at least 16 bytes of memory to store a single character (which is what happens with the single-character values that are not null terminated.

Comment: yes, it is a property of an exercise

Comment: sorry for bad code though

Comment: i just wanted to test my function, so i haven't looked at proper allocation for labels of a graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run on Mac OS X, I get the message:

```
graph(70806) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb211c03b20: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
```

With this annotated version of the `createList()` function:

```
static
void createList (adjList *list, vp graph, int *place) /* place stores an index in an array of adjacency lists */
{
    int i, temp = *place;
    adjList *ptr;
    if (graph)
    {
        printf("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
        list[temp].node = graph;
        list[temp].next = NULL;
        if (EDGE (graph))
        {
            ptr = list[temp].next;
            for (i = 0; EDGE (graph)[i]; ++i)
            {
                ptr = malloc (sizeof (adjList));
                ptr->node = EDGE (graph)[i];
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
        ++(*place);
        printf("About to realloc() in createList()\n");
        list = realloc (list, sizeof (adjList) * (*place + 1));
        printf("Back from realloc() in createList()\n");
        for (i = 0; EDGE (graph)[i]; ++i)
        {
            printf("Recursing in createList\n");
            createList (list, EDGE (graph)[i], place);
            printf("Back from recursive createList\n");
        }
        printf("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
    }
}
```

the output from the run is:

```
1
-->> createList()
About to realloc() in createList()
Back from realloc() in createList()
Recursing in createList
-->> createList()
About to realloc() in createList()
Back from realloc() in createList()
<<-- createList()
Back from recursive createList
Recursing in createList
-->> createList()
About to realloc() in createList()
graph(70904) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fefca403b20: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The trouble is that `createList()` reallocates the `list` passed in, but cannot tell the calling code the address of the new list.  You'll either need to revise `createList()` to return the new list, or arrange to pass an `adjList **list` into the function — in either case, with consequential changes.